# Is there a way to use Google Drive with JavaScript without Google Cloud Console?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm looking for a way to use Google Drive to share data between a Android app and a web page hosted on my server. The web page should use JavaScript to retrieve and store data in Google Drive.

The data should only be exchanged between the browser of the user and Google Drive.

According to the [documentation of accessing Google Drive from JavaScript](https://google-developers.appspot.com/drive/quickstart-js) you must first create a application using the Google Cloud Console, register it and get a client ID before you can use JavaScript to access the data.

I don't want to have to maintain a Google hosted application. Is this possible?

Comment: You'll notice that step of the instructions is the same for all the languages. The sample HTML also links to the client from Google's servers, and the documentation says "publish `quickstart.html` to *your* web server" – emphasis mine. Just from that I'd guess the application doesn't have to be Google-hosted. **tl;dr:** try and see before posting?

Comment: Sorry, the first step of the documentation to me made not clear the cloud platform is not for my application. I'll try to look closer in the future. So the answer is that it's not possible , but you only have to register the application (and first read the huge Terms of Service document carefully).

Answer (score 0):

The only point of apis console is to register your applicaiton or in your case script with google. Its baslcy just there way of keeping track of whos accessing what i think.  Once you have it registered you normaly would use a clientid and stuff as well as Oauth2 to allow users to access there google drive with your script.  But you wont need to go into that becouse its your application thats storing its data there and not a user.

You will probably want to look into a service account. 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/drive/service-accounts

Comment: I want a place to store/retrieve data of a user to allow them to switch between platforms (web & android app) and keep the data in sync. I don't think a service account will work for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use private spreadsheet then you have to use authentication, in this case google project is easiest one. If you don't want to use private then you can publish your spreadsheet and then make ajax call without authentication/goole project.

Comment: It's not to share between users, but for 1 user to share data between web interface and Android app.

Answer (score 0):

You're not the first person we've heard this complaint from. People want to be able to log in and create an API key without having to deal with extraneous cloud services. We're working on some things to make life easier for customers like you.

Unfortunately there is no way to do this at the present time. That said, you don't have to actually maintain a separate application. You can create a project and only use it to manage APIs.